# Bypass Sitecore for specific directories

Tags: configuration, iis

I'm not sure my title is ideal, so I am open to suggestions because I wasn't sure how to phrase it.

I am trying to create a Let's Encrypt cert using CertBot and it creates a file inside the /.well-known/ directory. The problem is that Sitecore tried to process the URL instead of letting the file be loaded in the browser.

How do I tell Sitecore to ignore any URL that starts with "/.well-known/" and just let IIS handle it as it would normally?

I tried IgnoreUrlPrefixes

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/trace.axd|/webresource.axd|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/telerik.web.ui.dialoghandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd|/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd|/sitecore/admin/upgrade/|/layouts/testing|/sitecore/service/xdb/disabled.aspx|/.well-known/" />
```

Comment: Have you tried `IgnoreUrlPrefixes` setting?

Comment: I did (I meant to mention that):     <setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/trace.axd|/webresource.axd|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/telerik.web.ui.dialoghandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd|/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd|/sitecore/admin/upgrade/|/layouts/testing|/sitecore/service/xdb/disabled.aspx|/.well-known/" />

Comment: What happens when you used IgnoreUrlPrefixes?

Comment: Nothing. I placed a test html file into the .well-known folder and I got 404 as before using the setting.